# I use pytorch to train a model to classify iris, but my acc was about 0.4

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, model, iris-dataset

I have tried many improvements like increasing epochs, using better loss functions and optimizers, deepening the network and shuffling the dataset, etc, but still to no avail. This problem has been bothering me for a long time, thanks for your help. Below is my code.

## load and process dataset(updated)

```
def Iris_Reader(dataset):
    train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.4)

    # scaler = StandardScaler()
    # train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
    # test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)
    
    return torch.FloatTensor(train_data), torch.LongTensor(train_label), torch.FloatTensor(test_data), torch.LongTensor(test_label)
```

## Define the classifier

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        #4*3*3 network
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(4,3),
            nn.ReLU(),

            nn.Linear(3,3),
        )
        
        #SGD
        self.optimiser = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr = 0.1)
        
        #MSE LOSS_FUNCTION
        self.loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

        self.counter = 0
        self.progress = []

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.model(input)
    
    def train(self, input, target):
        output = self.forward(input)

        loss = self.loss_fn(output, target)

        self.counter += 1
        self.progress.append(loss.item())

        self.optimiser.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimiser.step()
    # plot loss
    def plot_loss(self):
        plt.figure(dpi=100)
        plt.ylim([0,1.0])
        plt.yticks([0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0])
        plt.scatter(x = [i for i in range(len(self.progress))], y = self.progress, marker = '.', alpha = 0.2)
        plt.grid('on')
        plt.show()
```

## TRAIN

```
C = Classifier()
epochs = 10
dataset = datasets.load_iris()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_data, train_label, _, _ = Iris_Reader(dataset)
    for i, j in zip(train_data, train_label):
        C.train(i, j)
```

## TEST

```
score = 0
num = 0
# for epoch in range(epochs):
_, _, test_data, test_label = Iris_Reader(dataset)
for i,j in zip(test_data, test_label):
    output = C.forward(i).detach().argmax()
    if output == j:
        # print(C.forward(i).detach(), j)
        score += 1
    num += 1
print(score, num, round(score/num, 3))
```

OUTPUT: 53 60 0.883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of problems here:

- First, you seem to shuffle data and labels independently, rendering the dataset useless.
- Also, you recreate the dataset inside the loop every epoch, wasting the CPU time pointlessly.

Overall, the dataset creation can be shortened to something like this:

```
def Iris_Reader(dataset):
    train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.2)
    return torch.FloatTensor(train_data), torch.LongTensor(train_label), torch.FloatTensor(test_data), torch.LongTensor(test_label)
```

and should be taken outside the loop.

Next, `MSELoss()` is suited for regression. For classification, `CrossEntropyLoss()` is the default choice.

Using sigmoid as activation in an intermediate layer is not the best choice, especially with a short number of epochs. ReLU should converge much better.

Last but not least, your loss chart would look much cleaner if the values were averaged per epoch.

Update: the implementation that ensures the target having the same size as network output, with additional feature scaling:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def Iris_Reader(dataset):
    label = nn.functional.one_hot(torch.LongTensor(dataset.target), num_classes=3).float()

    train_data, test_data,train_label, test_label = train_test_split(dataset.data, label, test_size=0.2)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
    test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)
    return torch.FloatTensor(train_data), train_label, torch.FloatTensor(test_data), test_label
```

Oh, and you should probably also remove the final `Sigmoid()` since `CrossEntropyLoss()` applies logsoftmax anyway.

Comment: god, u r so professional! I modify it by above words, but i get another problem.

I change to use 4*3*1 NN, nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), and the edited Iris_Reader

`Using a target size (torch.Size([])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.`

①Do I have to change the label to onehot form every time?

Comment: You should keep the last dimension at 3, since there are 3 classes. Also updated the answer with a couple more improvements.

Comment: BRO, i just updated my code above. Thanks to you the acc improve so much, but it always run between 0.8~0..9  after StandardScaler(), the acc is sometimes very unstable and even jumps to 0.3. ①can I improve it better? ②Is my test code correct? Maybe the acc is unstable because of the tiny test data ③what should i do to make the loss chart cleaner, could you show me the code? I am ashamed about asking you so many noob questions, but i wish to improve myself. thank you!

Comment: It's often useful to make your code more deterministic while developing, using a fixed `random_state` arg to `train_test_split()` and a fixed `torch.manual_seed()`. This should ensure more or less reproducible results.

Comment: The dataset is not that big, so unlucky splits are possible. There might be some erroneous or outlying values present as well, a certain class may appear rarely. Perhaps you should cross-validate your model rather than using a single train/test split, for example, using `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold()` to get several train/validation splits and average the results, or applying [skorch](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch) wrapper for easier sklearn integration.

Finally, studying the metrics other than raw accuracy in order to see whether all classes are predicted equally well.

Comment: You can simplify accuracy calculation using `sum(C.forward(test_data).argmax(dim=1) == test_label) / len(test_label)` or `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(test_label, C.forward(test_data).argmax(dim=1))`

Comment: thanks for your help! I use others' code from github, i saw that they input the whole data to the model like `C.train(train_data,train_label)` instead of use loop like me `for i, j in zip(train_data, train_label): C.train(i, j)`. BUT I train model in this way, the acc is only about 0.6, is me or him was wrong?